# Add active state to <li> tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am not sure if this is possible. If not I could add an data-state or class, right?

Ok so my first question is... How can I add an active state on hover of `<li>` and remove it from previously hovered tag if new one is selected. I assume I need to use siblings for that but how do I make it go to :active I have no clues. If it's not possible any option from above seems fine... I just wanna learn how.

```
#menubar li {
    background: rgba(20, 20, 20, .3);
    margin: 10px 0;
    padding: 5px 0;
    width: 50%;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#menubar li:active {
    width: 100%;
}


<ul id="menubar">
    <li><a href="head.php">Head</a></li>
    <li><a href="body.php">Body</a></li>
    <li><a href="settings.php">Settings</a></li>
    <li><a href="">None</a></li>
    <li><a href="">None</a></li>
</ul> <!-- menubar CLOSE -->
```

so as mentioned im not sure if it is possible to add active state to `<li>` but still I need to ask.

If not something like this is more then welcome.

```
<li data-state="active"></li>
```

or

```
<li class="activeItem"></li>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use classes:

```
$('li').hover(function() {
    $(this).addClass('active');
}, function() {
    $(this).removeClass('active');
});
```

The `:active` pseudo class is only for links (as pointed out by Juan Mendes)

Comment: So there's absolutely no chance of data and :active ?

Alright... I will check it out, thought I need siblings for such a thing.

Comment: It's important to mention that `:active` is only for links

Comment: @JuanMendes ah I see.. same as focus for input fields. I just thought it might be possible :P 
Okay thanks for all informations guys! I really appreciate it.

Comment: This is for mouse overs, won't work when focus goes to the links

Comment: This works as expected. Thank you for simple and quick answer :)
@JuanMendes I understood :) ! Appreciate.

Answer (score 1):

You just do this -

```
$('li').hover(
    function(){
        $(this).addClass('activeState');
}, function() {
       $(this).removeClass('activeState');
});
```

Comment: If you have `$('li').removeClass('activeState');` in the first function then you do not need  the second argument to hover.

Comment: You do if you are moving from one 'li' to another. The second argument removes the class from all of them and nothing gets the hover state.

Comment: If you are moving, then the `mouseover` event for that `li` will be triggered which will remove `activeState` class for all `li` by `$('li').removeClass('activeState');` and then add it for the current `li`.

Comment: This is almost the same as Sidhart, but just looks a lot more confusing, and doesn't work

Comment: It absolutely works - did you try it? And it also requires only one class. http://jsfiddle.net/QXap5/

Comment: Sidhart's answer only requires one class too. This does work, but does unnecessary work (removes class `activeState` from elements that don't have it) Took my downvote back, but it's still inferior to Sidhart's. (Actually it won't let me take my downvote back until the answer is edited)

Comment: I can buy that it does unnecessary work by removing the class on mouseover but I have sen a lot of folks tripped up over this because they use $(this) improperly. I edited my answer, which norw makes it identical to Sidhart's.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to mouseover (suggested by Sidharth Mudgal) , is to use the focus event, which will work if you tab into the links

http://jsfiddle.net/QXap5/1/

```
$('li a').focus(function(){
  $(this).closest('li').addClass('active');
});

$('li a').blur(function(){
  $(this).closest('li').removeClass('active');
});
```